# Update Oracle table by amount of rows

Tags: oracle, sql-update

If I run the below query I m going to update an Oracle table by 7K rows. I want to do that by 300 of records per time.

```
INSERT INTO REQUEST
SELECT REQUEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL, REQUEST_ID, 'TEST', REF_ASK_ID, SYSDATE
FROM CITIES
INNER JOIN REFERENCE ON CITY_ID = REF_ID
WHERE REF_ASK_NM= 'DOWN'
AND CITY_WAY IN ('1', '33')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

300 rows at a time? Why? To make it slower?

Anyway:

- `rownum` will make sure to take 300 rows
- `not exists` will make sure not to copy what you already have copied (if where condition *catches* them all).

  - I don't know which columns belong to which tables as you didn't use table aliases (and yes, you should have)
  - if there are duplicates for columns being used in `where`, you might still get duplicates as there's no guarantee that that "set" of rows will be inserted as a *whole*

In other words: do it all at once.

```
INSERT INTO offices
   SELECT office_seq.NEXTVAL, office_id, office_ref
     FROM city INNER JOIN reference ON office_id = ref_id
    WHERE     ROWNUM <= 300
          AND NOT EXISTS
                 (SELECT NULL
                    FROM offices b
                   WHERE     b.office_id = city.office_id       -- or maybe reference.office_id
                         AND b.office_ref = city.office_ref);   -- or maybe reference.office_ref
```

Comment: because them should be processed

Comment: why select null in the second select?

Comment: Select anything you want; NULL is as good as "anything else"; the point is that this query returns (or doesn't return) any row(s) for conditions named in the WHERE clause).

Comment: I changed the query to include all the aspects of the AND